# 500 Internal Server Error: cannot update user in mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongoose, angular-fullstack, mongoose-schema

I am trying to run a put function to update a user in my mongoDB, but I am getting a 500 Internal Service error. I am using the [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) generator

I use this resource in my controller:

```
  update(User) {
    User.$update();
  }
```

Here are the functions I call in the backend to try and put the data everything seems to be working fine except for when I call saveUpdates, it seems like that is triggering the 500 error.:

```
function handleError(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 500;
  return function(err) {
    res.status(statusCode).send(err);
  };
}
// this seems to be the function giving me the problem. 
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    return updated.saveAsync()
      .spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
  };
}

function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
  };
}

function handleEntityNotFound(res) {
  return function(entity) {
    if (!entity) {
      res.status(404).end();
      return null;
    }
    return entity;
  };
}

export function updateUser(req, res) {
  if (req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
    }
```

I have tried following recommendations on [this](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/310) page for angular-full stack, such as changing ._merge to ._extend to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my question:

Angular-full stack utilizes lodash, so if you want to make put requests using ._merge like this:

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    return updated.saveAsync()
      .spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
  };
}
```

then you need to import lodash into the user.contoller set up by the angular-fullstack yeoman generator.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: Oh man, I had been trying to figure out why I was getting a 500 error after a merge, and I completely overlooked the exclusion of lodash! It's the little things...